How can I specifically "exclude" an element from a css grid/subgrid or position it correctly in a complex entanglement of nested grids…


* {
  outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
}

ol {
  *:not(li) {
    grid-area: none;
    /* hmmm... this is not right*/
  }
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-column: subgrid;
  li {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: subgrid;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

ol {
  counter-reset: Nr;
  *::before {
    font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    word-break: keep-all;
  }
  >li {
    counter-increment: Nr;
    &::before {
      content: counter(Nr) ".";
      text-align: end;
      margin-right: 0.85rem;
    }
    >ol {
      counter-reset: lit;
      >li {
        counter-increment: lit;
        &::before {
          content: counter(lit, lower-latin)')';
        }
        >ol {
          counter-reset: sublit;
          >li {
            counter-increment: sublit;
            &::before {
              content: counter(sublit, lower-roman) '.';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
<ol>
  <li>
    This is <strong>txt</strong> hi.
    <ol>
      <li>This li is not affected.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>



I would like to have all inline-elements such as the strong from the example behave normally and not get influenced by any grid/subgrid layouts… Also, everything in the same li after the strong element in the example is broken, too.
What I have tried so far is manipulating the display property and the grid property of any non-li item. My latest approach is in the code with a comment next to it.
It should look like this:
[
But the snippet output is:

Why I am using grid? I want to have maximum control over the width of the numbers/bullets, their "padding" (e. g. exactly centering a variable/unknown-width number in the "column of numbers") and the extent of indentation of any sub-lists...
For example: indent from the left should be exactly 1 cm while perfectly centering what ever bullet is being used + aligning numbers with different digit lengths to another correctly and letting any sub-lists numbering begin with its left edge exactly where the previous li text started... and so on, all at the same time and with granular control and maximum flexibility.

Please edit your post to (a) explain/illustrate your desired result, and (b) ensure that your snippet reproduces the actual results you have achieved so far.

I have attached a visual example of how the desired result should look like. What I have tried so far is manipulating the display property and the grid property of any non-li item. My latest approach is in the code with a comment next to it. But I don't think I am on the right path with it. At least the question could be more clear now.

And what are you trying to achieve by using grid? Please edit your post to explain this too. Your desired result looks an awful lot like a standard nested list, which doesn't need a grid.

If you just remove all the unnecessary grid styles and a lot of the styles in the top ol, you will achieve what you want: https://i.sstatic.net/zOG7vVz5.png This is a case of "less is more".

Please have a look at the paragraph "Why I am using grid?". Your example does not achieve this. @TylerH

@Adler I saw your paragraph, I just don't think it's relevant (or right). Lists have their own formatting which you can modify to your heart's content without using grid. If you try to force grid layout on a list you're just going to break things for no (good) reason. Use the built-in list layout styles, modifying them as necessary, or use grid layout and don't use built-in lists, if you for some reason need grid layouts. This is like trying to make a boat that can fly; you might be able to do it, if you really need to, but it's not going to be a particularly good boat or airplane.

grid-area: none; was wrong
instead I used display: contents;
Nested lists did not display correctly then. But this is just because they were not accounted for in the :not() function. Added ol and ul to the function.
Now everything displays correctly.


* {
  outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
}

li > *:not(ul, ol) {
    /* I have added ol, ul to the :not() function to make list nesting work again and improved the syntax*/
    
    display: contents; /* this fixes it */    
  }
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-column: subgrid;
  li {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: subgrid;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

ol {
  counter-reset: Nr;
  *::before {
    font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    word-break: keep-all;
  }
  >li {
    counter-increment: Nr;
    &::before {
      content: counter(Nr) ".";
      text-align: end;
      margin-right: 0.85rem;
    }
    >ol {
      counter-reset: lit;
      >li {
        counter-increment: lit;
        &::before {
          content: counter(lit, lower-latin)')';
        }
        >ol {
          counter-reset: sublit;
          >li {
            counter-increment: sublit;
            &::before {
              content: counter(sublit, lower-roman) '.';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
<ol>
  <li>
    This is <strong>txt</strong> hi.
    <ol>
      <li>This li is not affected.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>




I would consider float to achieve the same layout. I don't think CSS grid is the right approach.


ol {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden; /* this */
}

ol {
  counter-reset: Nr;
  *::before {
    font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    word-break: keep-all;
  }
  li {
    counter-increment: Nr;
    clear: both; /* and this */
    &::before {
      content: counter(Nr) ".";
      text-align: end;
      margin-right: 0.85rem;
      /* and this */
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      float: left;
      /**/
    }
    ol {
      counter-reset: lit;
      li {
        counter-increment: lit;
        &::before {
          content: counter(lit, lower-latin)')';
        }
        ol {
          counter-reset: sublit;
          li {
            counter-increment: sublit;
            &::before {
              content: counter(sublit, lower-roman) '.';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
<ol>
  <li>
    This is <strong>txt</strong> hi.
    <ol>
      <li>a <a href="">link</a> here.
          <ol>
            <li>a <a href="">link</a> here.</li>
            <li>This li is not affected.</li>     
          </ol>
      </li>
      <li>This <strong>li is not</strong> affected.</li>
      <li>This li is not affected.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>This li is not affected.</li>
  <li>This li is not affected.</li>
</ol>




This is the grid solution you are looking for.
The key to the solution (and yes, it is slightly annoying) is to add some extra wrapper elements in your HTML. For any <li> which contains another explicit element such as <strong> or <a>, wrap its entire contents with another element ... I have used a <div>. (Of course, you can make it easy by just adding the additional wrapper inside every <li>.)


ol {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: l1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 0 0.5em;
}

ol > li {
  list-style: none;
  display: contents;
}

ol > li::before { 
  content: counter(l1) '.';
  counter-increment: l1;
}

ol ol {
  counter-reset: l2;
}

ol ol > li::before { 
  content: counter(l2, lower-latin) ')';
  counter-increment: l2;
}

ol ol ol {
  counter-reset: l3;
}

ol ol ol > li::before { 
  content: counter(l3, lower-roman) '.';
  counter-increment: l3;
}
<ol>
  <li>
    <div>
      This is <strong>txt</strong> hi.
      <ol>
        <li>
          <div>a <a href="">link</a> here.
            <ol>
              <li>
                <div>
                  a <a href="">link</a> here.
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>This li is not affected.</li>     
            </ol>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            This <strong>li is not</strong> affected.
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>This li is not affected.</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>This li is not affected.</li>
  <li>This li is not affected.</li>
</ol>



